# Yii2 attributeLabels not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii 2, and my basic API is working fine and now I am trying to change the field names which are returned from the database, 
so I have added `attributeLabels()` in my model and changed the name for the fields but it's not reflecting.

Can any one help me on this? Below is my model code (this is for API).

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'LOGIN' => 'Login',
        'FIRST_NAME' => 'First Name',
        'LAST_NAME' => 'Last Name',
        'EMAIL_ADDRESS' => 'Email Address',
    ];
}
```

Do I have to add anything in my controller? I have only `actionIndex` to return all the records. Below is the code from my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    $model = Phdlist::find()
            ->limit(100)
            ->all();
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the attribute labels are  used for display purpose  and don't became the key of the model  attribute..
In your function  seem you need  to return a collection of models (in JSON_FORMAT)

in the collection you retrieve  the name of single object attribute is based on the keyname:

```
    'ID' 
    'LOGIN' 
    'FIRST_NAME' 
    'LAST_NAME' 
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can you please help me to covert the name to user readable name..

Comment: If you are sending this result to a client that process this result in javascript you could add a proper attribute as  a column title and process this attribute .. otherwise  .. you should explain bettere what  you want to do with this resulting json converted  model ..

Comment: I am getting the result set as field name in tables , but i dont want to show the table name , so i want to change the field ...

Comment: I don't understand  try update  your question and add a proper sample .. please

Comment: My table i have field name as 

    'ID' 
    'LOGIN' 
    'FIRST_NAME' 
    'LAST_NAME' 
    'EMAIL_ADDRESS'
and i dont want to show in my result as same .

So i want to show the result as

     "ID": 1,
    "USERNAME": "loginname",
    "FIRST NAME": "some name",
    "LAST NAME": " some name1",

Now i getting result as

     "ID": 1,
    "LOGIN": "loginname",
    "FIRST_NAME": "some name",
    "LAST_NAME": "some name1",

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then it looks like you should be using `yii\base\Model::fields()` to solve your problem.

Checkout http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#fields, especially the section titled **Overriding `fields()`**.

> By default, `yii\base\Model::fields()` returns all model attributes as
>   fields, while `yii\db\ActiveRecord::fields()` only returns the
>   attributes which have been populated from DB.
>
> You can override `fields()` to add, remove, rename or redefine fields.

Here's a relevant example (specially `'email' => 'email_address'`) from that page -

```
// explicitly list every field, best used when you want to make sure the changes
// in your DB table or model attributes do not cause your field changes (to keep API backward compatibility).
public function fields()
{
    return [
        // field name is the same as the attribute name
        'id',
        // field name is "email", the corresponding attribute name is "email_address"
        'email' => 'email_address',
        // field name is "name", its value is defined by a PHP callback
        'name' => function ($model) {
            return $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name;
        },
    ];
}
```

You need add this to your Model code. In your case, it would be `'login' => 'username'`. However, please bear in mind attribute names cannot have spaces. So `'first_name' => 'first name'` wouldn't work, as far as I know.